# dig returns different IP address when dropping the "www." from domain name

Tags: ip, dns, domain

I have performed a dig on my domain name used on my site and I seem to be getting different results when I drop the "www." from the lookup. I am concerned this is causing me issues within my application, however i'm not sure if it's a red herring or not.

When I do this:

```
 dig @8.8.8.8 www.php53.staging-crm.com
```

I get:

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.php53.staging-crm.com. 14400 IN A    165.160.xx.xx
www.php53.staging-crm.com. 14400 IN A    165.160.xx.xx
```

Similarly, when I drop the "www.":

```
 dig @8.8.8.8 php53.staging-crm.com
```

I get:

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
php53.staging-crm.com. 14400 IN  A       80.75.xx.xx
```

(full IP addresses have been removed).

What would cause these to return different IP addresses?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Whatever `dig` reports is the truth.  You should conclude that `www.php53.staging-crm.com` maps to 165.160.x.x and `php53.staging-crm.com` maps to 80.75.x.x.

There is no particular reason why they should map to the same address.  It is common these days to have the unadorned domain name map to the same address as `www` for the convenience of web users, but that is nothing more than a convention.  Your domain's entries just aren't defined that way now.

Comment: Within my application I use the PHP function fpassthru, within my hosts file I map 127.0.0.1 to www.php53.staging-crm.com so I was concerned that as dig didn't report the same IP for both with and without the "www" then this could be an issue.

Comment: dig is a DNS lookup utility, and does exactly that.  It ignores /etc/hosts.  It ignores /etc/nsswitch.conf.  Therefore, your web browser might get different results when it performs hostname-to-address lookups.

Answer (score 2):

Actually the domain name `www.php53.staging-crm.com` is the child domain of `php53.staging-crm.com`. They may or may not map to the same address. In your case both are mapped to two different IP addresses.

Comment: Do you believe this should be a problem if I have more than one instance of Apache?

Comment: I never thought about it that way but that makes an embarrassing amount of sense...